# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

**I want to add an option but where do I have a mistake?**

```
conn=sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')
c=conn.cursor()

def create_table():
  c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (UNIX REAL, datestamp TEXT, keyword TEXT, value REAL)')

def data_entry(a,b,c,d):
  c.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ({}, '{}', '{}', {})".format(a,b,c,d))
  conn.commit()
  c.close()
  conn.close()
#create_table()
data_entry(1,"test","test2",3)
```

Comment: you use the same name `c` to keep `c=conn.cursor()` and to assign `"text2"` in `def data_entry(a,b,c,d):` so finally you have `"test2".execute(..)`

Comment: can you edit code? i dont know

Comment: simply use different name for one of variable. I suggest to use `curr = conn.cursor()` as in @DeveshKumarSingh answer. This name better describe its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a local variable `c` in `def data_entry(a,b,c,d):` which is being passed as a string, and is used as an `execute` function, which ends up doing `"test2".execute()`.

That issue needs to be fixed. And one fix is if I explicitly use `curr` as a variable to represent the cursor.

```
conn=sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')
curr=conn.cursor()

def create_table(curr):
  curr.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (UNIX REAL, datestamp TEXT, keyword TEXT, value REAL)')

#curr is the last argument
def data_entry(a,b,c,d, curr):
  curr.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ({}, '{}', '{}', {})".format(a,b,c,d))
  conn.commit()
  curr.close()
  conn.close()

#Explicitly passing curr to functions
create_table(curr)
data_entry(1,"test","test2",3, curr)
```

In future ensure you name your variable short and descriptive, like `curr`, and perhaps the strings as `val_1`, `val_2` etc. So that you know from the name what the variables are used for.

This is a good resource for variable naming: [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id45)

Comment: `'{}'.format(s)` IS PRONE TO SQL INJECTION ATTACK. It may have been safe for the OP's use case but future readers must be aware that this is generally a bad practice. To know more and learn an easy, safe alternative, see https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/.

Answer (score 2):

In your original code your local parameter `c` shadows the global cursor variable `c`. You should pass the cursor and connection as arguments:

```
def create_table(cursor):
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (UNIX REAL, datestamp TEXT, keyword TEXT, value REAL)')


def data_entry(cursor, conn, a, b, c, d):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ({}, '{}', '{}', {})".format(a, b, c, d))
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()


conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

create_table(cursor)
data_entry(cursor, conn, 1,"test","test2",3)
```